# Tortoise SVN sub folder accessibility issue

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have created a **repository** using **tortoise SVN**. The repository seems to work fine but I am **struggling** to make a sub folder **in accessible**. Even setting the sub folder to have **no access**, when a user tries to fetch the **repository**, **whole directory** is fetched **including** the **sub folder** which has been set to be **in accessible**.

[image: 1]]

Comment: Presumably **you** have access to it, so Tortoise, using your credentials, will have access to it too. Can you add the folder to an ignore list?

Comment: I tried fetching from first user, who has no access, and yet folder is fetched correctly. Please refer to snap's list of user where 1st one has no access against its name.

Comment: How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3728455/1364007)?